# How to get "neg str" in key argument of sort/sorted function easily?

Tags: python, sorting

I want to sort list by multikeys with different orders(increasing or decreasing).
for `int` and `float` values, I can easily use unary `-`. For example, I want to sort a list by first value increasing, second value decreasing, third value increasing. I can write key function like

```
key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1], x[2])
```

but how to do it when value type is `str` or others?

Some data is below:

```
numlist = [(2, 0.5, 1), (1, 1.3, 2)]
numlist.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1], x[2]))
strarr = [('jam', 'Peter'), ('apple', 'sf')]
def multikeys(item):
    pass
strarr.sort(key=multikeys)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the old Python 2 `sort` method (with a `cmp` argument) using the built-in `cmp` function (see below for more information about it) was superior to purely key-based sorting.

```
def compare_items(x, y):
    return cmp(x[0], y[0]) or cmp(y[1], x[1]) or cmp(x[2], y[2])
    #                             ^^^^^^^^^^
    # Note the arguments in the second call are swapped.

numlist.sort(cmp=compare_items)
```

You can simulate this in Python 3, but it's a bit unwieldy. The `functools` module includes a class that uses an old-style comparison function to create callable objects that are suitable for use as a key function.

You still need to re-implement `cmp`, though. It was removed entirely, rather than just being "demoted" to the standard library.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key


def cmp(x, y):
    if x < y:
        return -1
    elif x == y:
        return 0
    else:
        # x > y implied by the required total order
        return 1


def compare_items(x, y):
    # As before
    ...


numlist.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare_items))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to sequentially sort them:

```py
strarr = [('jam', 'Peter'), ('apple', 'sf'), ('jam', 'Fred'), ('apple', 'mel')]
strarr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
strarr.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
print(strarr)
# [('apple', 'sf'), ('apple', 'mel'), ('jam', 'Peter'), ('jam', 'Fred')]
```

Edited as per user2357112's comment.

Comment: [This gets the priority wrong](https://ideone.com/L8wsNK) - it prioritizes ordering by second elements over ordering by first elements. You need to swap the `sort` calls, so `strarr.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)` is the first sort.

Comment: @user2357112, yes you are correct, will adjust.

Comment: @user2357112 although to cater for casing, I'd be inclined to use DUCET, or better yet CLDR tailoring for the UCA. Rather than the default sort. So take the above solution and extend it to use a different collation algorithm and collation weights.